# Looping in Wordpress with Pods Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, podscms

I am trying to create a loop for a group of divs that are being entered in as Pods via Wordpress admin panel.

I have the Pods setup. I could have them setup improperly, but I believe they are setup correctly. I have one Pod and the info is as follows:

**Pods Information:**

- Label: advisors
- Name: advisor
- Type: Custom Post Type
- Storage Type: Meta
- Number of Fields: 2

**Field 1 Information:**

- Label: Advisor Name
- Name: advisor_name
- Field Type: Plain Text

**Field 2 Information:**

- Label: Advisor Title
- Name: advisor_title
- Field Type: Plain Text

The HTML I am trying to replicate is:

```
<div class="small-container text-center advisor-list">
      <h1 class="text-center">Header Title</h1>
      <div class="row  gutter-0 padding-30 text-center vpadding-30 ">
             <div class="box column large-3 vpadding-10 medium-3 text-center">
                    <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/icon-star.png">
                    <h2>Name</h2>
                    <h4>Title</h4>   
            </div>
            <div class="box column large-3 vpadding-10 medium-3 text-center">
                    <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/icon-star.png">
                    <h2>Name</h2>
                    <h4>Title</h4>   
            </div>
            <div class="box column large-3 vpadding-10 medium-3 text-center">
                    <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/icon-star.png">
                    <h2>Name</h2>
                    <h4>Title</h4>   
            </div>
            <div class="box column large-3 vpadding-10 medium-3 text-center">
                    <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/icon-star.png">
                    <h2>Name</h2>
                    <h4>Title</h4>   
            </div>
    <button id="showPartners" class="bttn bttn-4 bttn-4a vpadding-30">View Our List of Partners</button>
</div>
```

This is as far as I have gotten with the PHP:

```
<div class="small-container text-center advisor-list">
  <h1 class="text-center">Header Title</h1>
  <div class="row  gutter-0 padding-30 text-center vpadding-30 ">
    <?php 
      function get_the_pod($pod_name, $pod_fields, $order = 'name'){
      $item_no=0;
      $pod = new Pod($pod_name);
      $pod->findRecords($order);
      while ($pod->fetchRecord()){
        foreach ($pod_fields as &$field){
          $results[$item_no][str_replace(".guid","",$field)] = $pod->get_field($field);
            if($field == end($pod_fields)){$item_no++;}
        }
      }
      return $results;        
      }

     ?>
         <?php $fields = array('name'); ?>
         <?php $advisors = get_the_pod('advisors', 'name DESC'); ?>
         <?php  foreach($advisors as $advisor){ ?>
           <div class="box column large-3 vpadding-10 medium-3 text-center">
             <img  src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/icon-star.png">
             <h2 ><?php echo $item['advisor_name']; ?></h2>
             <h4><?php echo $item['advisor_title']; ?></h4>           
           </div>
     <?php } ?>  

    <button id="showPartners" class="bttn bttn-4 bttn-4a vpadding-30">View Our List of Partners</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has any input, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Pods 1.X methods. Here is much simpler code using Pods 2.X methods. 
You will want to check out the docs pages for [`pods()`](http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/) and [`pods::find()`](http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/find/), which has the infromation about how to set `$param` for `pods()`, for more information.

```
         <?php 
                $param = array( 'orderby' => 't.name' );
                $advisors = pods('advisors', $param );

                foreach($advisors as $advisor) { 
                   $advisor_name = $advisor->field( 'advisor_name' );
                   $advisor_title = $advisor->field( 'advisor_title' );
         ?>
             <div class="box column large-3 vpadding-10 medium-3 text-center">
                  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/icon-star.png" />
                  <h2><?php echo $advisor_name; ?></h2>
                  <h4><?php echo $advisor_title; ?></h4>           
             </div>
        <?php } //end foreach
        ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to make a couple changes to make it work, but that made it work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Pods posts within loop using core Wordpress loop type and structure, you can use it with your own data values

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <div class="entry">
    <?php
      $team = new Pod('sliders');
      $team->findRecords('slider_number ASC');       
      $total_members = $team->getTotalRows();
    ?>
    <?php if( $total_members>0 ) : ?>
      <?php while ( $team->fetchRecord() ) : ?>
        
        <?php
          // set our variables
          echo $member_id        = $team->get_field('id');
          echo $member_name      = $team->get_field('post_title');
          echo $number      = $team->get_field('slider_number');
          echo $img      = $team->get_field('slide_img._img');
        ?>
        
      <?php endwhile ?>
    <?php endif ?>
      
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: https://jonchristopher.us/blog/pulling-pods-data/